# What are layouts in Node.js's Express Library?

Tags: layout, node.js, express

I'm disabling this feature because I don't know what it is:

```
app.set('view options', { layout: false });
```

But It sounds interesting so I would like to know why was this designed, so I would like to know what are the usage cases and why is this good :)

Comment: layout is for the default layout. It's the equivelant of an ASP.NET master page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the [View Rendering](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering) section it tells you about layouts.

It's a way to apply generic HTML wrappers to all your pages.

For example [Reference](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/jade/views/layout.jade)

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    title Blog
    link(rel='stylesheet', href=base + '/style.css')
  body
    #container!= body
```

Is a layout for an example from the express folder. This will be applied to all pages and your actual view that your rendering will be rendered in `!= body`

Comment: But I don't really understand, as I read in the express docs I'ts just a way to specify the `view engine` into jade, ejs or something like this. But then what is this snippet from you? what is passed into the `body` ?

Comment: @CIRK the actual view. Layout is the option to use a layout _page_. The view rendering engine is specified elsewhere. What server-side technology have you used in the past?

Comment: wait a little, maybe I've got it, so I can specify for example a layout: index.jade where other rendered jade files will be passed like in your example, then in index.jade I can call them as 'header', 'footer', 'content' etc...?

Comment: @CIRK yes exactly that's what layout is for. Used any particular PHP framework?

Comment: No I haven't I don't really like frameworks in general if it's possible I like to write my own, I use express only on Node because It's greatly implemented with Jade with partials etc.. :) And because I'm new with node I can learn a lot from express about how Node.js works by looking at functions and sources :) Node is not as easy as PHP was(in terms of logic):P

Comment: The concept of "layout" was removed in Express starting from 3.x.